# How to prevent HTTP and allow HTTPS?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How to check the URL is `http` or `https` through programmatically using `HttpServlet`. If the Url is `http` send message as `Warning` otherwise message as `Allow`.

How to prevent HTTP Url and allow HTTPS through programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect HTTPS inside a servlet via `servletRequest.isSecure()`.

To force use of HTTPS, just [configure secure Urls](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Secure_URLs) in your `web.xml`. The when users go to HTTP they will be redirected to HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks. In the `configure secure Urls` can be redirect from other protocols to `https`. My question is how to prevent other protocols. When we have use `https` allow the web page, otherwise block/prevent Other protocols.

Comment: For example when users use this URL `http://appengine.google.com` in this URl is automatically redirect to `https://appengine.google.com`. I don't like this mechanism. For example I need when users use this sample URL `http://appengine.google.com` browsers redirect to `404` or `505` or any Error Message. Is it possible?

Comment: Only with custom Servlet Filter: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html

Comment: Thanks. Any other solution to prevent http without filter.